# Error when launching emulator in Android?

Tags: android

I have this error when i lunch the android emulator? why ?

```
[2011-04-20 19:39:23 - Yamba] Android Launch!
[2011-04-20 19:39:23 - Yamba] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-20 19:39:23 - Yamba] Performing course.class1.YambaActivity activity launch
[2011-04-20 19:39:23 - Yamba] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'adham2' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-04-20 19:39:23 - Yamba] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'adham2'
[2011-04-20 19:39:23 - Emulator] unknown option: -http-proxy="http://192.168.2.1"
[2011-04-20 19:39:23 - Emulator] please use -help for a list of valid options
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put a `=` with the options

```
-http-proxy "http://192.168.2.1"
```

Comment: How do you launch you emulator? Your error says `unknown option: -http-proxy="http://192.168.2.1"`. You did not put it by hand?